# javascript object when is it created

Tags: javascript

I am doing the following in javascript:

```
    var first_last = { FName: 'John', LName: 'Smith'};
```

When I do the above with the `{}`, does that make `var first_last` an object?

Wouldn't `alert(JSON.stringify(first_last))` show me the content of the object?

Comment: `JSON.stringify` makes json object to string

Comment: Yes, that will declare `first_last` with a value that's an object. Did you even try it?

Comment: @safarov: No it doesn't. It makes a normal object into a JSON string. Big difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed. It's an object and you can check if if is calling `typeof first_last;`. Should return `"object"`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and yes. It works for me. ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nUF5j/)) If you're having an issue, it lies elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Depending on your JSON library you may need to put LName and FName in quotes.